# How to Change qty2 from var total = rate2 * qty2 Dynamicaly with select box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

Let's say I have this HTML:

```
<select id='list'>
                        <option value='qty2'>Meter</option>
                        <option value='pcs2'>Pcs</option>
```

and then I have the js

```
  var rate2 = Number($("#rate_value_"+row).val());
  var qty2 = Number($("#qty_"+row).val());
  var pcs2 = Number($("#pcs_"+row).val());
  var total =  rate2 * qty2 
  total = total.toFixed(2);
  $("#amount_"+row).val(total);
  $("#amount_value_"+row).val(total);

  subAmount();

} else {
  alert('no row !! please refresh the page');
}
```

so i wanna change `var total = rate2 * this(selected from option value)`, can this be possible?

Comment: I am having a hard time figuring out what you are trying to do. couple of questions: 1) why does your js include an '_' after 'qty' and the html does not? 2) how would you expect a string that includes text, being converted to a number be anything other than 0?

Comment: Just retrieve the value of #list and use that for the id prefix instead of the string literal? Or what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get that specific dropdown value then do it like this.you will get the qty2 value you want to multiply,Then pass the value to the multiplication

```js
var qty2;
function ddval(){
  if($('#list :selected').val()=='qty2'){
  qty2=$('#list :selected').text();
  alert(qty2);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="list" onchange="ddval()">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="qty2">Meter</option>
  <option value='pcs2'>Pcs</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected value of `select` using jquery

```
 var total =  rate2 * $("#list").val()
```

It will give value of selected option either `qty2` or `pcs2`